# How to import play in scala repl

Tags: scala, playframework, read-eval-print-loop

How can I import play in Scala repl?

```
scala> import play.api.libs.json._
<console>:11: error: not found: value play
       import play.api.libs.json._
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**1)** setup simple build tool(sbt) {its easy - download from here - http://www.scala-sbt.org/download.html and instructions here - http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Installing-sbt-on-Windows.html}

**2)** Create a empty folder with `build.sbt` with following contents

//your-test-project/build.sbt

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"                                                                               

resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"                    

libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play" % "2.5.12"
```

**3)** Then simply do `sbt console` on the root on folder, which will download play and make it available to your console.

```
$ ls -l ~/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.play/play_2.11/jars/
total 15392
-rw-r--r--  1 as18  185223974  4107407 Jan 22 15:59 play_2.11-2.5.12.jar
```

Then you are good to go.

```
scala> import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.json._

scala> val json: JsValue = Json.parse("""{ "compiler" : "scala", "ratings" : 5 }""")
json: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = {"compiler":"scala","ratings":5}

scala> val compiler = ( json \ "compiler" )
compiler: play.api.libs.json.JsLookupResult = JsDefined("scala")
```

*Also, you can directly provide the jar if you already have it as below*

```
scala -cp ~/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.play/play_2.11/jars/play_2.11-2.5.12.jar

scala> import play.api.libs._
import play.api.libs._
```

Answer (score 4):

Things are much simpler with [Ammonite REPL](http://www.lihaoyi.com/Ammonite/#import$ivy):

```
load.ivy("com.typesafe.play" %% "play" % "2.5.12")
import whatever.you.need
```

Comment: is it available for Windows 10? Couldn't find its download page.

Comment: @ManuChadha your fault to use windows in 2017 :) You probably need bash for windows so that you can execute the script - `sudo curl -L -o /usr/local/bin/amm https://git.io/vMF2M && sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/amm && amm`

Comment: Would have given a Like to your comment if there was an option :)

Comment: glad I found your answer.

Answer (score 3):

The package is not found because it is not in the class path of the REPL.
If you know the location of Play Framework's JAR on your computer, you can add it to the class path when starting the REPL:

```
> scala -cp path/to/play.jar
```

You can also add this directly from inside a REPL session:

```
:require play.jar
```

Note that you will still need to import your classes as before.

Comment: I downloaded play-2.2.6.zip. Started REPL using `c:\..\play-2.2.6.zip` Then used `:require play-2.2.6.zip.` Got success message `Added 'C:\Users\Manu\Documents\manu\play-2.2.6.zip' to classpath.` but still got error when used `import play.api.libs.json._`error: not found: value play`

Comment: are you saying you added `play-2.2.6.zip`  or `play.2.2.6.jar`? You should import `*.jar` not `.zip`